# While loop with if/else statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So I am still in the process of learning Python and I am having difficultly with `while` loops.  I have a sample of code below that includes `while` loop and `if` and `else` statements.  What I want it to do is print 'Less than 2' and 'Greater than 4' which it does, but it keeps running.  It does not print it just once each which is what I would want it to do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
counter = 1
while (counter < 5):
    count = counter
    if count < 2:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        print('Less than 2')
    if count > 4:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        print('Greater than 4')
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Your counter is incremented to 2, after which you just keep hitting the else statements and printing in an infinite loop.

Comment: *It does not print it just once each which is what I would want it to do* Is this Chinese or Tamazight?

Comment: And now after your edit it does exactly what one would expect it to do. Add 1 on each increment where a condition holds and what is printed makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
counter = 1 
while (counter <= 5): 
    if counter < 2:
        print("Less than 2")
    elif counter > 4:
        print("Greater than 4")
    counter += 1
```

This will do what you want (if less than 2, print this etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to say `Less than 2` or `Greater than 4` while incrementing from 1 to 4:

```
counter = 1
while (counter < 5):
    if counter < 2:
        print('Less than 2')
    elif counter > 4:
        print('Greater than 4')
    else:
        print('Something else') # You can use 'pass' if you don't want to print anything here
    counter += 1
```

The program will never display `Greater than 4` because your while condition is `counter < 5`.

Answer (score 1):

What a while-loop says is if True, keep doing till False. If you watch automate the boring stuff- While Loops on YouTube it should give you a understanding of   how a while loop can be used and why a if-statement can be best in other cases..

```
password = ''

while password != 'your password':
    password = input('Please enter your password... ')
print('Thank you')
```

1. Variable *password* is set as a blank string
2. *password* is not an input equal to string "your password", which makes the while expression True, while true repeat. if *password* does equal 'your password' expression is false, exit loop.
3. While *password* equals anything except 'your password', expression is True, repeat loop till False.
4. If loop becomes False, print end of line, 'Thank you', end program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a variable called username1 and assign a value to it
2. Declare a variable called password1 and assign a value to it
3. Declare a variable called isCorrect and assign to it the boolean value True
4. Create a program that asks the user to enter his username (variable name: username2) and password (variable name: password2) and save them
5. The program will check if the entered username (username2) and password(password2) are the same defined in username1 and password1
6. if Yes print HAPPY LOGIN
7. if not ask again the user to enter new values and check again

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions and answers. I fail to see how this answer is answering the question asked.